# Is it possible to ask browser: "Send NTLM authentication, but only if you have credentials ready"?

Tags: http, ntlm

In our application we support both users authorized with NTLM in a certain intranet domain, and users authorized with a standard login/password pair which we store in our database. When a new user registers, it would be nice to know if he has NTLM credentials and just prompt him to use these, instead of a generic registration form.

I.e. something like (in pseudocode):

```
if user.has_ntlm_credentials:
    ask ("You are known as {domain}\{username}, register in the application?")
else:
    show_login_password_registration_form ()
```

If I make the page send back 401 HTTP code and ask for NTLM notification, I will get the above *if* the user is authenticated already (e.g. comes from that intranet and uses Windows). But for every other user browser will show ugly authentication dialog, which looks ridiculously out of place on a registration page.

So, question is, **is it possible to ask browser for already available NTLM credentials, if any?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; but you could instead use Negotiate, which would require that the user has an existing Kerberos ticket (via Active Directory authentication, in this scenario) to authenticate. There would be no prompt for users who did not have a ticket.

NTLM and Negotiate different authentication mechanisms:  NTLM is a simple challenge/response mechanism while Negotiate is the encapsulation of the more secure (and more complex) Kerberos protocol.  Both mechanisms are available to allow "single sign-on" where a Windows user needs only to authenticate once, when logging on to their computer, and subsequent network connections will be authenticated using those logged-in user credentials.  (Though Negotiate will *only* work when domain joined to Active Directory, while NTLM can work in a workstation setup.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar with this topic. Does that mean using some completely separate authentication method (this is out of question for us, we have externally imposed requirements), or do we still talk about the same stuff, just asked from browser in a different way?

Comment: I'm afraid that it is separate.  NTLM and Negotiate are different mechanisms that attempt to achieve a similar end ("single signon").  If you have a requirement that you *must* use NTLM then I suspect that Negotiate will be too different.  If your requirement is merely that you use "Windows authentication" then Negotiate may satisfy that requirement.

Comment: OK, thank you. I need to clarify the requirements because on one hand, what they want is to achieve SSO with our application, but on the other hand they refer to NTLM everywhere in the specification.

Comment: Doesn't "Negotiate" authentication mean: try to use Kerberos otherwise fallback to NTLM? I think you mean to say "Kerberos" in all instances of the word "Negotiate" in your answer.

Comment: Technically, yes, but that's not really the practical implementation.  There's the NTLM mechanism - which is only NTLM.  Then there's Negotiate, which could technically be NTLM or Kerberos, but in practice anything that speaks NTLM doesn't actually use the Negotiate mechanism, it just goes ahead and uses NTLM.